# Android 12(Api Level 31): TfLiteGpuDelegate Invoke: GpuDelegate must run on the same thread where it was initialized

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow-lite

After upgrade my android os to version 12, my code stopped work, I use flutter plugin tflite_flutter 0.9.0 and I launch tflite in isolation.

It throws this error:

```
TfLiteGpuDelegate Invoke: GpuDelegate must run on the same thread where it was initialized.
E/tflite (20055): Node number 64 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to invoke.
E/flutter (20055): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(1111)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (20055): Bad state: failed precondition
E/flutter (20055): #0 checkState (package:quiver/check.dart:74:5)
E/flutter (20055): #1 Interpreter.invoke (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:150:5)
E/flutter (20055): #2 Interpreter.runForMultipleInputs (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:190:5)
E/flutter (20055): #3 Classifier.predict (package:myai/ai/tflite/mobilenet/object/classifier.dart:179:19)
E/flutter (20055): #4 IsolateHelper.entryPoint (package:myai/ai/helper/isolate_helper.dart:51:30)
```

My code:

```
final gpuDelegateV2 = GpuDelegateV2(
options: GpuDelegateOptionsV2(
isPrecisionLossAllowed:true,
inferencePreference:TfLiteGpuInferenceUsage.preferenceSustainSpeed,
inferencePriority1:TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.minMemoryUsage,
inferencePriority2:TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
inferencePriority3:TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
)
);
var interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions()..addDelegate(gpuDelegateV2);
_interpreter = interpreter ??
await Interpreter.fromAsset(
MODEL_FILE_NAME,
options: interpreterOptions
);
```

Anyone faced such problem? Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the error you encounter is
`Can not open OpenCL library on this device - dlopen failed: library "libOpenCL.so" not found`?
Version 12 requires modules to [declare dependencies in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/reference/compat-framework-changes#enforce_native_shared_library_dependencies). When targeting Sdk version S you need to add the TFLite dependencies to your manifest. Read the follow relevant comment taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu).

> Note: You can now target Android S+ with targetSdkVersion="S" in your manifest, or targetSdkVersion "S" in your Gradle defaultConfig (API level TBD). In this case, you should merge the contents of [AndroidManifestGpu.xml](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/AndroidManifestGpu.xml) into your Android application's manifest. Without this change, the GPU delegate cannot access OpenCL libraries for acceleration. AGP 4.2.0 or above is required for this to work.